# Может ли TomCat удерживать файлы "открытыми"?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

Всем привет. Буду благодарен за разъяснение. Ситуация следующая - есть класс, генерирующий отчет в формате .docx на основе уже существующего вордовского файла. Данные для отчета приходят в сервлет в POST-запросе. Отчеты генерируются, данные подставляются, все хорошо. Но, при проверке локально, выяснилось, что после генерации отчета, файл шаблона не может быть изменен, пока работает TomCat, на котором крутится сервлет. При попытке что-нибудь в нем изменить Ворд ругается на ошибку доступа. При пробном запуске напрямую из Eclipse - все нормально, файл отчета освобождается корректно, изменения, если нужно, проходят без проблем. Вывод - что-то "удерживает" файл незакрытым, помимо сервлета. Варианты - или TomCat, или Spring. Второе - как по мне, маловероятно, но в спринге я совсем слаб. Собственно вопрос - что мне нужно изменить и где, чтобы файл шаблона не оставался "заблокированным"? Кода там много, потому не выкладываю, но если нужно - выложу. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вы закрываете все открытые файлы и потоки?

Comment: Само собой. Собственно, если запускать не из под TomCat, а просто из Eclipse -  все отрабатывает корректно.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос как вы запускаете

Comment: Разобрался. Помогло добавление в TOMCAT_HOME\conf\Catalina\localhost файла host_manager.xml  со строкой "<Context antiResourceLocking="true" />" 
Все равно - спасибо за участие.